# Eclipse: Create jar containing one class + dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an eclipse project that contains several classes and packages. I want to create a runnable jar of just one class from the project. But this jar should contain all the dependencies too. Can someone please tell me how can I do this? Most posts on StackOverflow have answers for creating a jar file for the entire project, but I only need jar of one class with all dependencies bundled together.

Comment: How are you creating the build ?

Comment: Do you mean the other classes of the project are dependencies?

Comment: I am using ant. And no, the other classes are not dependencies. Infact this class doesn't have any other classes in my project in its imports, but has imports of some other classes that are part of jars in my project.

Answer (score 2):

I could finally figure out how to do it. Just right click on your class file for which you'd like to create a jar. Select Export --> Jar File. Click on next. In select resources to export, select the project name. Expand the project to find the package that contains the class you'd like to export as a jar. Select the class name. Check the box --> Export generated class files and resources. Select the export destination, and check the option --> Compress the contents of the JAR file. Click on next. Under select options for handling problems, leave both the options checked. You don't need to check the option - Save the description of this JAR. Click on next. Here, leave the default options. Under select the class of the application entry point, specify your class (Make sure your class has a main method). And finally click on finish. Once this is done, go to the path where you've saved the jar. Right click, and say open with --> Archive utility. This will create a folder of your jar file. In my case, I named the folder lib. Inside this folder, copy all the JARs that this class needs to execute.

Finally, do this from the folder where you have the folder of your jar file --

```
myMac$ JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
myMac$ libraries=`ls lib/*.jar | tr "\n" ":"`
myMac$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp $libraries com.test.rick.GeoData
```

GeoData here is the class which I was trying to export as a JAR. Hope this is useful for someone in the future.