# How to build jar with only one Java class from large NetBeans project

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using NetBeans and have a Java project with many packages each containing many class files. None of these classes contain a main method as they are called from a larger program.

How can I build a jar file from this project with only one of those classes and include all libraries required for that class? I am currently right-clicking on the project in the "Projects" pane of NetBeans and selecting "Clean and build", which builds the entire project.

**Example: build a Jar file containing only the `com.andrew.overflow.questions.foo` class from the following project:**

```
> AndrewOverflow (Project)
> > com.andrew.overflow.questions (Package)
> > > Foo (Class)
> > > Bar (Class)
> > com.andrew.overflow.answers (Package)
> > > Some (Class)
> > > None (Class)
```

When I search for this question, I only find how to *import* single classes when I'm looking for how to *export* (or "build") single classes.

Comment: I dont get you. JARs are for multiple class files in the first place. What makes you think that any single java class in that huge project could be used when **all** of its surrounding buddies are not with him?

Comment: @GhostCat I'm using a system that reads my JARs and runs the single class that I specify in that system. `What makes you think that any single java class in that huge project could be used when all of its surrounding buddies are not with him?` Because I designed it that way. Each class is a stand-alone program to be run on its own within the system. I could create separate projects for each class, but then I have to manage the same library files in each project. I understand that JARs are for multiple class files. I want my JAR to only contain the class files I specify. How do I do that?

Comment: *"How can I build a jar file from this project with only one of those classes?"* By only specifying to include that .class file when building the .jar file. Of course, since you didn't say *how* you're currently building the .jar file, we can't tell you what to change, but you *could* look at the [**documentation**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) for the `jar` command.

Comment: *FYI:* Your classes are badly named. [Java naming convention](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2697/oracle-official-code-standard/9031/naming-conventions#t=201611252032164436565) is that class names use mixed case with the first letter in each word in upper case (i.e. [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)), so class names should be `Foo`, `Bar`, `Some`, and `None`.

Comment: @Andreas I updated my example to be consistent with Java naming convention (although I do follow this in my projects). I also edited the question to include how I'm currently building the JAR. I'm asking how to do this within NetBeans and am looking for a solution using the NetBeans UI. If no such UI solution exists, then I will resort to the `jar` command.

Comment: Similar question for the Eclipse IDE here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354782/eclipse-create-jar-containing-one-class-dependencies

Comment: Very unlikely that you can do that directly from NetBeans, since NetBeans does the standard thing, similar to Maven, of creating one jar from one project. You can of course always create an Ant script (or similar) and run that from NetBeans. That is what build tools like Ant are for.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. Now, since this is my first post on SO, any advice as to why my question has received -3? I included background research, explained my situation, clearly stated the question, and provided sample context. In future questions, what should I do differently (or in addition)?

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans 8.1, right-click your project and go to **Properties**. In the **Sources** menu, click the **Includes/Excludes** button.

To include only the Foo class, you would enter `**/Foo.java` into the **Includes** field. To add the entire .questions package, you would enter `**/questions/**`. Multiple includes are separated by a comma.